# Is there any option to get the price of XLM via python stellar_sdk or API?

Tags: horizon, stellar-sdk

For example XLM = $0.3537 now

Is there any option or API&SDK script for it?

or Do I have get it from other website?

Answer (score 1):

There is a build in DEX in Stellar and you can query the [orderbooks](https://developers.stellar.org/api/aggregations/order-books/) for other assets but I guess you will find APIs by coingecko.com, coinmarketcap.com or others more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

USD is external to Stellar, so enquiring Stellar will not work. But from the Stellar network you can get XLM/USDC rate, which you can retrieve / calculate from the order book (assuming USDC == USD)

or using https://ticker.stellar.org/ (https://www.stellar.org/developers-blog/a-new-ticker-for-the-stellar-community?locale=en)
I don't know how reliable is the ticker page, I would rather use orderbook.

Or use API for coingecko.com or coinmarketcap.com, as @alpe1 advised.